# Customize/Simplify bootstrap-package

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use solely the carousel-component of bootstrap 4, but I don't feel comfortable using the complete css-bootstrap-file for just that one component. Isn't there something to use just the needed elements without identifying things manually? (This goes especially for the css-file, I'd be alright using the default js-file. )

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can customize and download the files from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/

Hope this helps you.